# Is there a way in Python to iterate through a full script?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a script using Pandas and Rest API to facilitate a way to get data from the source. The script includes a series of for loops and conditional functions which creates a dataframe that is output into Excel.

The URL of the API has a numeric value that determines the exact source, and until now we have only been able to input one value at a time, run the script, get the data, rinse and repeat. I would like to know if there is any way to enter multiple values and rerun the entire script for each initial input value.

I tried creating a list in the beginning and writing a for loop at each required step. This works perfectly well, but we have 6 different scripts that this must be applied to, and I was wondering if there is an easier way to write the code so that it can rerun the whole script and output to the same file.

Comment: Wrap the entire script in a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: Or you could use a shell loop to run the script multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: Or turn every script into a large function and `import` them as modules and iteratively pass params.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to automate this is with a bash script.  Consider:

```sh
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo $i
done
```

This should be runnable in your terminal (if you are using one) and it will print the numbers 1 through 5.  To run your python script, you could do something like:

```sh
for i in {1..5}
do
   python my_script.py $i
done
```

And your script will run on inputs 1 through 5.

If you would rather keep everything in Python, you could try the following:

```py
#looper.py
import subprocess
for i in range(5):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'my_script.py', str(i)])
```

```py
#my_script.py
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```